# Count function in SQL but with a query passed in?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do something like this:

```
select
    EmployeeID e,
    SupervisorID s
from
    ReportingStructure
where
    count(select SupervisorID from ReportingStructure where EmployeeID = e) > 1
```

to find the employee ID and supervisor IDs of all employees who have more than one supervisor. But I get a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

How can I get this data?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Instead you can just use a window function `COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ...`

Comment: You can't write code in whatever syntax you want, and expect SQL Server to understand and execute it.

Comment: I understand I can't make up my own syntax; I'm saying I tried this and it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get them on separate rows using `exists`:

```
select EmployeeID, SupervisorID
from ReportingStructure rs
where exists (select 1   
              from ReportingStructure rs2
              where rs2.EmployeeID = rs.EmployeeID and
                    rs2.SupervisorID <> rs.SupervisorID
             );
```

If you want the supervisors in one row, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select EmployeeID, string_agg(SupervisorID, ',')
from ReportingStructure
group by EmployeeID
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Never would have occurred to me to check for the existence of records with the same employee ID but different supervisor iDs!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you'd be better off with a query like this, as then you don't have 2 scans:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT EmployeeID AS e,
           SupervisorID AS s
           COUNT(EmployeeID) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID) AS c
    FROM dbo.ReportingStructure)
SELECT e, s
FROM CTE
WHERE c > 1;
```

Comment: I think you want `COUNT(EmployeeID)...` to be `COUNT(SupervisorID)...`, Larnu.

Comment: Assuming that both are non-`NULL` it doesn't actually make a difference, @EricBrandt .

Answer (score 0):

Try having clause:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID e,
    SupervisorID s
FROM
    ReportingStructure
HAVING COUNT(SupervisorID) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function as

```
SELECT EmpId, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId) Cnt
FROM
(
    VALUES
    (1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3)
) T(EmpId)
```

If you want to return the rows where `Cnt > 1` then

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT EmpId, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId) Cnt
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
        (1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3)
    ) T(EmpId)
) TT
WHERE Cnt > 1;
```